# extension library rest control Xpages

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I am using extension library Rest controls ViewJsonservice to provide the data from Notes database, is there a easy way using same control I can provide the data from two databases, I can put the similar view from dbA to dbB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no

Long answer:
I presume you want the data from 2 views available in a single endpoint. Either after each other (appended) or somehow merged.

You can do that using code. Check [this article](https://wissel.net/blog/2014/10/custom-rest-service-in-xpages-using-a-service-bean.html) for basic info.

In a nutshell: use the ViewNavigator class in both databases to retrieve results and append or merge the data before you return it.

Nice side effect : you can return all the data.